# Access directory while mod rewrite is on

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess file to keep my URL's clean

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1 [B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2&get3=$3
```

It works so far, but I now want to access a directory.

For example. If someone goes to mysite.com/news/post-title, the URL is rewritten and everything is ok.

Now I want to have a directory that can be viewed when someone goes to mysite.com/directory and have it's contents shown.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `RewriteCond` in front of each `RewriteRule`, to force the `RewriteRule` to be skipped if the request is made to a location that's a directory and exists.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1 [B]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2&get3=$3
```

All that's going to get you is the actual directory listing.  If you want to allow the users to also access the files within those directories, you should also add a condition to each of those checking for file existence:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: while googling for an answer, i came across RewriteRule ^(dir_name|file_name\.extension|and_so_on) - [L]. Seems to get things done. Is it worse? Am I taking some risk by using it?

Comment: @AnPel That will also work, but requires you to have a known list of locations.  If you've only got a single specific location that you need to account for, that will work great!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like the following;

```
<Location /Somedirectory>
    Options Indexes
</Location>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule ^/Somedirectory - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1 [B]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2&get3=$3
```